# Django celery page is giving 404

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, celery-task, celerybeat

I'm trying to acces `https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html` but getting 404. Is celery not officially available?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I had the same issue yesterday. Google indexed results pointed me to the old URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The celery documentation has moved: https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html